# How to use a modified third-party library in a Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, heroku

Some background:

Currently, I'm using the [Coderay](http://coderay.rubychan.de/) gem (v 0.9.7) in a Rails project that I'm working on.

I downloaded the source code for that version and applied a patch for a functionality that the Coderay team is planning to release in later version.

Questions are:

1. How do I use this modified code in my project?
2. I'm using [Heroku](http://heroku.com/) for the live site. How do I use the modified code in the live site since now I'm not using the official gem?

Comment: +1 because I've run into this myself many times. I answered with the two solutions that I tend to end up with, but I'm certain that there might be a third or fourth good option as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

## 1. Custom gem

You could stick your modified gem source up on github, and then tell Bundler to use your code.

In `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'coderay', :git => 'git://github.com/ryanprayogo/coderay.git'
```

(Or whatever the actual path ends up being.)

## 2. Evil twin

The other option would be to do an Evil Twin in your vendor directory. It's something like a pattern for hacks that you want to keep separate from your library code.

http://errtheblog.com/posts/67-evil-twin-plugin